# Get ACF Taxonomy selection in Block and display fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

Figured this would be pretty easy but I am running into an issue.

The website I am building, the client has a list of taxonomies that have an ACF Image Field and ACF Description field.

What they want to do is have a block where they can select certain ingredients from the Taxonomy Block, then have it render out formatted  (on a page)(At this time it doesnt need to link to the actual category) but they want to do it this way so they dont need to update page by page when an ingredient changes description or image they can just change it in the taxonomy list.

Below is the code i am using to try and get it going from the docs, it wont render the name or original description it will render the slug but skips over the name but the slug is correct

I've been trying this with no luck, it just returns 3 li's which is correct but i can get a name or custom field to come through.

If i just the the_field('ingredients_selector');  I get the ID's just fine But for the life of me i can not get a term name or the ACF field attached to it/

```html
$terms = get_field('ingredients_selector');
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<ul class="ingredients-list">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li class="ingredients-list__item">' . $term->name . '</li>'; ?>
        <p>Description: <?php the_field('description', $term); ?></p>
        <p>Image: <?php the_field('image', $term); ?></p>
    <?php }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

I've also tried this way, this gives me same reuslt but the slug with work, it will skip term name again but "view all" will link at least

```html
<?php
$terms = get_field('ingredients_selector');
if( $terms ): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
<li>
<h2><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></h2>
<p>Term description: <?php the_field('description', $term); ?></p>
<p>Term Image: <?php the_field('image', $term); ?></p>
<p><?php echo esc_html( $term->description ); ?></p>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>">View all '<?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>' posts</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Attached is my set up of the ACF fields

EDIT****

This was my solution

```html
<?php 
        $tax = 'ingredients';
        
        $terms = get_terms( $tax, $args = array(
          'hide_empty' => false, // do not hide empty terms
        ));
        
        
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
            $image = get_field('image', 'ingredients_' . $term->term_id );
            $description = get_field('description', 'ingredients_' . $term->term_id );

        
            if( $term->count > 0 ) {
               echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">';
                echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] .'">';       
                echo $term->name .'</a>';
                echo $description;
        
            } elseif( $term->count !== 0 ) {
                echo '' . $term->name .'';
                
            }
        }
                
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `<?php the_field('image', $term); ?>` to `<?php the_field('image', 'term_name_'.$term->term_id); ?>`. (replace `term_name_` with your actual term slug)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and replace `term_name_` with your actual term slug:

```
<?php
$terms = get_field('ingredients_selector');
if( $terms ): ?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
    <li>
        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></h2>
        <p>Term description: <?php the_field('description', 'term_name_'.$term->term_id); ?></p>
        <p>Term Image: <?php the_field('image', 'term_name_'.$term->term_id); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo esc_html( $term->description ); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>">View all '<?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>' posts</a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can find more about this [**here**](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/#get-a-value-from-different-objects).

Comment: Thanks for your help, my confusion is how do I get the term slug? Isn't the name the term Slug which Im trying to get?

Comment: It was a bit misleading on my side. The slug as I meant is the name of the taxonomy. You can see it in the URL after `taxonomy`. Here's the category URL for example: `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category`. You can see it in the URL if you open your taxonomy in the backend

Comment: So my url like that is /wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=ingredients

`<p>Term description: <?php the_field('description', 'ingredients_'.$term->term_id); ?></p>`

OR

`<p>Term Image: <?php the_field('image', 'ingredients_'.$term->term_id); ?></p>` I am still returning nothing, am I missing something stupid simple?

Comment: Ahhh i got it sort of --- It doesnt take it from the block like i wanted but the block can use the tax set in the sidebar and that is good enough. Thank for all your help, edited my answer above